# Python: How to pass a replacer function with parameters, to re.subn

Tags: python, eval

I want to replace expressions between two markers, with the return value from eval'ing that expression, however, I want to pass the locals() context of where the re.subn is being called to the function that evals the expression.

```
  contents, count = re.subn("<py>(.+?)</py>", **self.pyexec**, code), contents, 99, re.DOTALL)
```

(No way to pass parameters in the subn replacer function).

I need to do this, effectively:

```
  contents, count = re.subn("<py>(.+?)</py>", **self.pyexec(locals())**, code), contents, 99, re.DOTALL)
```

But that won't work because in that case, pyexec is no longer a function name/pointer, but a call to self.pyexec. Some languages let you "bind" parameters to a function and make it into a functor that has the bound parameter explicitly, but everything I look up about "bound" functions in Python only applies to the self parameter. Not what I need.

Another solution might be if there is away to get the locals() of one stack frame up. I'll research that.

Comment: Pre-supplying some of the parameters to a function to be called later is generally called *currying*, or *partial application*.  The formal solution to that in Python is `functools.partial()`; the usual way people do it is to write a `lambda` that calls the actual function with additional parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Coming from a C++ world where it's called bind(), I think currying is the more specific and better word for it.